# Combine an unknown number of flags into a bitwise or statement

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-or

Some software requires the passing of parameters via a bitwise OR statement.
EG

`Foo.SetFlags( flag1 | flag2);`

When you have a known quantity it's easy enough to write this in code. However, what if I have a variable number of flags that I only know at runtime?

For example I had a dynamically created list of flags like `List<Flag> flags;` - How would I combine them all in a bitwise OR statement programmatically?

Comment: Can you sum them?

Answer (score 1):

Start with 0x0; then use subsequent ORs in foreach loop.